# What VPN router can restrict access to VPN tunnel via MAC address?

Tags: router, vpn

We're currently using Netgear DGFV338 routers to provide VPN access to the office from home locations. But I don't think it can restrict access to the VPN tunnel based on MAC address.

Does anyone know of any router (within the same price range!) that can do:

- ADSL(2+)
- Wireless
- VPN
- Restrict access to VPN tunnel based on MAC address

The scenario being: I want to be able to use the VPN tunnel from my computer, but if a friend came over and connected his laptop to my home network, can I prevent him from using the VPN tunnel and only give him 'normal' internet access?

Is this possible?

EDIT: I'm looking for a hardware-only solution if possible. Other software solutions I've seen only work with Windows. I'm using a mix of operating systems at the remote end of the tunnel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a DGFV338 connected to your home DSL line, which bridges your entire home network with the office network. If you have a separate broadband modem, the solution is pretty straightforward--just put another router in between the modem and the DGFV338, and only let your friends connect to this new "public" router to get on the Internet.

You probably will also want to configure the public router on a different subnet than both your office network and your private router, because traffic from the private router may have trouble traversing the network otherwise.

Also note that the computers on your private network should be able to access anything on your public network, but computers on the public network should be blocked from the private network unless the DGFV338 is configured to route the other direction.  This should be the case already, but you may want to confirm it before allowing anyone onto the public network.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Took a while to sink in, but makes sense now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The [NetGear website](http://www.netgear.com/Products/VPNandSSL/WirelessVPNFirewallRouters/DGFV338.aspx) suggests that your friend's laptop would have to have the NetGear software and a valid license installed and configured for your office network, so I don't think you need to filter based on MAC address.

The typical install scenario appears to be that you install the router at your office and install the VPN software on the employees' laptops or home computers.  If this is your configuration, then it looks like it's handled via a software-based authentication scheme, and your friend's laptop won't be able to connect to the office router without installing the NetGear software and using your security credentials.

Comment: I'm not so sure. I've never installed the NetGear software, and all machines on the LAN have access to the tunnel.

Comment: So you have a DGFV338 connected to your home DSL line, which bridges your entire home network with the office network?  If you had a separate broadband modem, the solution would be simple--just put another router in between the modem and the DGFV338, and just let your friends connect to this new "public" router to get on the Internet.

Comment: Unfortunately the NetGear software only works on Windows PCs - we have a mix of other OSs as well. I've edited my question after you mentioned the software. I'm really looking for a pure hardware solution.

Comment: @rob: regarding adding an intermediate 'public' router, I understand this now and I think this is the solution. I can't accept this answer however, since it relates to a software solution. If you want to write another answer I'll up-vote it and make it the accepted answer.